# TensorFlow: Is there a way to convert a list with None type to a Tensor?

Tags: tensorflow

For my application, I am trying to convert a list with `[None, 1, 1, 64]` to a tensor using `tf.convert_to_tensor([None, 1, 1, 64])`, but this gives me the error:

`TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <type 'list'> to Tensor. Contents: [None, 1, 1, 64]. Consider casting elements to a supported type.`

Ideally, I want `None` to be the first dimension because it represents the batch_size. Currently, the only way I could avoid this error is to explicitly give the batch_size to the operation, but I am hoping there is a cleaner way to convert such a list to a tensor.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, because `None` and `64` have different types, and all tensors are typed: You can't have elements of different types in one tensor.

The closest thing you could do is `nan`:

```
tf.convert_to_tensor([np.nan, 1, 1, 64])
```

although I can't imagine why you'd want that.

You can however create a `TensorShape`:

```
tf.TensorShape([None, 1, 1, 64])
```

Answer (score 2):

Use tf.convert_to_tensor([-1, 1, 1, 64]) instead of None, since you are already specifying 3 out of 4 dimensions, this should be fine.