# How convert a list with None in it to torch.tensor()?

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

For example I have a variable `z = [1, 3, None, 5, 6]`

I would like to do: `torch.tensor(z)`

and get something like the following:

```
torch.tensor([1,3, None, 5,6], dtype=torch.float)
```

Howhever, such attempt raises an error

> TypeError: must be real number, not NoneType

Is there a way to convert such list to a `torch.tensor`?

I don't want to impute this `None` value with something else. Numpy arrays are capable of converting such lists `np.array([1, 3, None, 5, 6])`, but I'd prefer not to convert back and forth variable either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you do. Probable the best is to convert `None` to `0`.

Converting things to numpy arrays and then to Torch tensors is a very good path since it will convert `None` to `np.nan`. Then you can create the Torch tensor even holding `np.nan`.

```
import torch
import numpy as np

a = [1,3, None, 5,6]
b = np.array(a,dtype=float) # you will have np.nan from None
print(b) #[ 1.  3. nan  5.  6.]
np.nan_to_num(b, copy=False)
print(b) #[1. 3. 0. 5. 6.]
torch.tensor(b, dtype=torch.float) #tensor([1., 3., 0., 5., 6.])
```

---

Try also `copy=True` inside [`np.nan_to_num`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.nan_to_num.html) and you will get `nan` inside your tensor instead of 0.

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what I wanted. 
Howhever, while None objects can be compared, it seems that nan objects can't be ([nan] == [nan] returns [0] instead of [1], while [None] == [None] returns [1]). Is there any way to compare nan with other nan?

Comment: `np.nan==np.nan` will return `False`. This is an old problem with the IEEE 754 standard. We can just use [`isnan`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html).

Answer (score 2):

[I have a feeling that the tensor construction from data source doesn't allow the same kind of leniency that Numpy has with allowing `None` types](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.tensor). Please see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44280135/tensorflow-is-there-a-way-to-convert-a-list-with-none-type-to-a-tensor) for a discussion where others have asked about None types in tensors.

Looks like you're going to have to think about how to handle your missing data, either through imputation or another form of data cleaning.

Or perhaps a [tensorshape](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/TensorShape) is what you need.